# jQuery select value not set

Tags: jquery, syntax

I am trying to set an action for when a select value is between 0 and 2, but with the function below, I am getting the action triggering when the value is not defined. What is the best method for doing so?

```
$('#html_select').click(function(){   
    var option = $(this).val();   
    if(option < 3 && option != null){  
    //Do something
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly fine.

It is usually better to use the `onchange` method:

```
$('#html_select').change(function(){   
    var option = this.value; //DOM's value   
    if(option < 3 && option != null){  
    //Do something
   } 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/pFFAH/

Comment: Thanks for the .change(). I still have the problem of when the select value equals '(an empty string)' the if statement is true. Is null the wrong thing to be using? I tried undefined with the same result.

Comment: try using `option != undefined` which you should not have to use since all of your options have values, correct?

Comment: Check this jsfiddle for a better example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pFFAH/1/ and click on the empty value.

Comment: @danixd, why do you have an empty option?

Comment: @Neal it is just the way the form works, it has an empty value on all select boxes as default. Unfortunately this is something I cannot change.

Comment: You need to add an extra check: if(option < 3 && option != null && option != ""){} That will check against an empty string. the null check is normally not much use.

Comment: @Henry Garle it feels really messy, I would have imagined null|undefined == ' '. Oh well! :)

Comment: Your right danix but when used like this the trouble is it is neither null or undefined, its an empty string :) if you ever want to do an undefined check in JS just for referance its: if(typeof id != "undefined") {}

Comment: @Henry Garle an empty string should be null. Afff. It is empty! '' is nothing. I will remember this small technicality. Thanks again.

Comment: @danixd Haha, I know. It really frustrated me coming from other far more strict programming languages to JS, I would recommend (if you haven't already) getting firebug. It really is one of the most useful tools around.